# CreationTime not working while LastWriteTime is working

Tags: powershell

i have this Script

```
    [Cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        #$LogTimestamp = "$($CurrentYear)_$($CurrentMonth)_$($CurrentDay)",
        [Parameter()]$LogPath = "C:\Admin\scripts\Clean_Folder\Log\$(Get-Date -UFormat '%d_%m_%Y_%H.%M.%S')__Clean_Shared_ALLE_Log.txt",
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$Message
    )
    process {
        $timeStampedMessage = "[$(Get-Date -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm' )] $Message"
        $timeStampedMessage | Out-File -FilePath $LogPath -Append
    }
}

Function Remove_FilesCreatedBeforeDate{
# Pfad der durchsucht werden soll inklusive aller Unterordner
$Path="\\servername\Share\"

# Festlegen wie alt die Dateien sein sollen
$Date=(Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$ValidPath = Test-Path $Path -IsValid
If ($ValidPath -eq $True)
 {

"Path is OK and Cleanup is now running" | Write-MyLog 

# Loggen welche Dateien älter als X Tage sind
"The following files will be deleted" | Write-MyLog 
Get-ChildItem -Path \\EVOF9001\Data\Shared_ALLE\ -Recurse -File | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $Date } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Write-MyLog

# Dateien älter als X Tage löschen
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse  -File | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $Date } | Remove-Item -Recurse -force -verbose -whatif | Write-MyLog
} 
Else {"Path is not a ValidPath" | Write-MyLog}
}

Remove_FilesCreatedBeforeDate
```

This Script is working as expected with my personal User. Now i have created a AD-User who has the same access group for the share like my user. But the Script isnt working. I found out that this line isnt giving back anything

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\servername\share\ -Recurse -File | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

But when Using LastWriteTime its working

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\\servername\share\ -Recurse -File | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

I have like no idea why its not working with the CreationTime :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the misstake... There where no more files older then 30 days. Just in one sub folder but this sub-folder wasnt accessbile by the Service-User because someone changed the access rights.

So yeah the script is working perfectly.

Comment: Perhaps delete the question then, because I don't think someone else could benefit from it as there was no problem with the code..